# How can I exclude questions by a user (aka only include answers by a user) in search?

Tags: support, user-interface, search

To find out all of the posts I made (say, in [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter) tag), I can [search for](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:976%20%5Bharry-potter%5D) "user:976".

But that includes ALL posts made by the user, both answers and questions.

Can the search be refined to include only the answers (or exclude any questions)?

Comment: Dupe-closing this since I've now posted a definitive proposed-FAQ question about the search facility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the search page](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=) yes you can.  Just add `is:question` or `is:answer` to only get questions or answers in your search results.